# how to get the request path without converted the path parameter in Spring Boot Webflux

Tags: spring-webflux

I have a route defined as follows

```
@Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> testRouter() {
    return route(GET("hello/{test}"), intervalHandler::helloTest);
}
```

How to get the path pattern `hello/{test}` using serverWebExchange `ServerWebExchange` in the Filter component?

Comment: Do you need a pattern or a final path?

Comment: I would like to have the pattern.

Comment: Then the easiest way is just to pass a pattern as an argument. Like `route(GET(pattern), request -> interval.helloTest(request, pattern))`

Comment: It works, but if I need to catch this pattern in the filter tier. Any suggestion for me?